# How do I hide my menu when viewing on mobile devices?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, woocommerce, nav

My website is http://sitandwonder.com.au built in wordpress using woocommerce.

I don't like the way my menu looks on mobile at the moment with my current theme.

I found a way to add a responsive menu using a plugin but what happens is I end up with 2 menus. Is there a way I can input some custom CSS to hide my old menu without hiding the new plugin menu?

Comment: Mate if you do not know how to add CSS to a website you should probably  google the basics instead of asking on StackOverflow. There are hundreds of possibilities how to add CSS in WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have the following menu:

```css
nav{
  width: 80vw;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgb(43,43,43);  
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 678px){
  nav{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>option 1</li>
    <li>option 2</li>
    <li>option 3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Adding the CSS rule `@media` will allow you to detect and apply styling depending on screen orientation: `landscape,portrait`, whether its `handheld` device, or just by determining the screen width: `min-width,max-width`, these are called [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

**MAKE SURE YOU RUN THE CODE SNIPPET IN FULL SCREEN, OTHERWISE NOTHING WILL SHOW...**

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to check if current device is mobile in wordpress

```
<?php if(is_mobile(){
    load_your_mobile_menu();
}else{
    load_your_desktop_menu();
}?>
```

/* Replace load_your_mobile_menu() and load_your_desktop_menu() by your respective menus for mobile and desktop*/

Answer (score 0):

put this into your style.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
div#responsive-menu-container,
button#responsive-menu-button,
header#header {
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

Install this plugin [WDES Responsive Mobile Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wdes-responsive-mobile-menu/)

Add this code below or after the body tags. Normally this can be found on header.php of your template.

```
<?php wdes_rmm_mobile_responsive_menu(); ?>
```

Problem solve.